# Exclude or remove sub list from original list in Laravel

Tags: php, list, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a many-to-many relation between Order and Item table.
This relationship is defined in Order model:

```
public function items()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Item', 'order_item', 'order_id', 'item_id' );
}
```

If customer is adding an item to the order, he choose one item from a list

```
$items = Item::all();
```

and this chosen item is add in intermediate (pivot) table (order_id, item_id).

The problem is that, I need my items list to contains only these items which have NOT been chosen for this order before. i.e. pivot table does NOT contains these items combined to this specific order.

Pseudo code:

```
$all_Items = Item::all();
$previously_Selected_Items = select_From_Pivot_Table::where('order_id', '=', $id);
$required_Items_List = $all_items->exclude($previously_Selected_Items);
```

I'm using Laravel 4.2.
Any suggestions??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time of searching and trying some suggested ideas, I came up with easy, but not professional, solution:

```
$order = Order::where('id', '=', $id)->with('items')->first();
$allitems= Item::all();
```

then array_diff, a php function, did the trick:

```
$items = array_diff($allitems->lists('name','id'), $order->items->lists('name','id'));
```

but the $items is just a list of id and name, not the whole objects, which I need. So I need a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `whereDoesntHave` and filter the items using the relationship:

```
$items = Item::whereDoesntHave('orders', function($q) use ($id){
    $q->where('order_id', $id);
})->get();
```

Comment: Could u, plz, redirect me to an explanation of 'whereDoesntHave' for better understanding of its job. I searched the web but found nothing about it. @lukasgeiter

Comment: Take a look at `whereHas` in [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#querying-relations). `whereDoesntHave` is basically the opposite. It will select all items that don't have a related model `Order` that matches the condition (`order_id = $id`)

Comment: `whereDoesntHave` seems not to be exist. Any how, I'm trying `whereHas` and it returns an empty array, so far. Any suggestions?

Comment: It returns this error `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'doesnt_have' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `item` where `doesnt_have` = orders)`

Comment: You probably need to update Laravel. (`composer update`) `whereDoesntHave` has been added in mid-december last year

Comment: Updating caused my project to crash. Fortunately, I kept a copy. Thank u any way.

Comment: Well if you can't update you can use `whereHas('orders', function(...), '<', 1)`